# Getting errors when trying to create a PROCEDURE in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a mysql stored procedure, but I get this error:

> Script line: 2 Failed to CREATE PROCEDURE proc_test_bideep

The stored procedure code is:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `commun`.`insert_categorie` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `commun`.`insert_categorie` (id_mere INT,
                                                                lib_categ VARCHAR(50),
                                                                id_categ_sup INT ,
        categ_authInstantBuy INT)
BEGIN
SET @bg_mere := (SELECT categ_bg FROM categ_basic WHERE categ_id = id_mere);
  
 @bg_mere+2,categ_level_bideep,categ_statut,categ_adult,categ_authSmallBid,categ_authBid,categ_authInstantBuy);
        SELECT '1' AS code_retour;   END IF;
ecetera.........
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

a) You need to DECLARE any variables on the first lines of the procedure, including their datatype:

```
DECLARE bg_mere INT;
```

b) To fetch a value from the database into a variable, you use SELECT ... INTO syntax:

```
SELECT categ_bg INTO bg_mere FROM categ_basic WHERE categ_basic.categ_id = id_mere;
```

c) You have an END IF without the corresponding IF.

d) The closing END needs a semicolon (not BEGIN though), only then do you need a delimiter to finish the entire statement, and finally you should reset the delimiter back to normal:

```
BEGIN
  # body of the stored procedure goes here
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters are missing the keyword **IN** such as: ...(IN id_mere INT, IN lib_categ ...). Also, you need to configure your **OUT** variable for *@bg_mere* in the initial parameter list such as (IN xxx, ..., OUT bg_mere VARCHAR/INT/WHATEVER).